# How to maintain constant width of MudSelect element in RowEditingTemplate

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am running into an issue where the width of my MudSelect element will change based on the length of the selected item when it is within a RowEditingTemplate.

In order to demonstrate the issue, I have added the a MudSelect element to the "Position" column in this table; it is viewable below.

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYQlEZFYAZZAOlWs

How can I format this so that the length of the MudSelect does not vary based on the length of the selection?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:

```
@foreach (var item in positionList)
                {
                    <MudSelectItem Value="@item">@item</MudSelectItem>
                }
```

If you do this instead:

```
@foreach (var item in positionList)
            {
                <MudSelectItem Value="@(item.Name)" />
            }
```

Then the width should be static.

Comment: I took a look at the OPs code and the items do not have a name. They're just `int`. Furthermore, it can have serious consequences because now we do not refer to the object by reference but by names which aren't necessarily unambiguous. Please elaborate.

Comment: any progress on this @Jan?